Small Resistors on Power Supplies of Lattice iCE Development Kits?
What is the function of R30 and R35 in the Lattice iCE development kits (iCE40HX-8K Breakout Board or iCEstick)? One possibility I've considered is that they help limit ramp rates or control the power-up sequence by quickly discharging large capacitors. However, pulling over 40 mA in this manner seems quite costly. What other reason are these resistors included?
The image is part of the schematic from iCE40-HX8K Breakout Board User's Guide that can be found here.

Hint: look at the voltage rail above each resistor you asked about and look a bit further to the right at the other voltage rail.

As per site rules, could you please edit the question to provide the link to the schematic?

Usually resistors such as R30 and R35 are incorporated to ensure that there is a minimum load on the voltage regulator as some regulators require that.
The LT3030 (Datasheet) does not seem to require a minimum load though, so I believe the resistors are not necessary and can be removed from the circuit.

I can confirm that, at least short term (hours), everything is functional without them
